# Arduino with mosquitto mqtt

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

When I ran the Mosquitto (MQTT) broker for the first time there was no issue. However when running it for the second time using the default config I could not run the code successfully because of the following error on Windows 8:

`1379497253: mosquitto version 1.2 (build date 2013-09-17 17:59:39+0530) starting 1379497253: Using default config. 1379497253: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883. 1379497253: Error: Address already in use`

How can I resolve this error, or more importantly what does this error mean?

Answer (score 2):

`Address already in use` usually means that the port (in your case `1883`) is already being used by another process. The most likely situation given your description is that another copy of mosquitto is already running. If you want to run two (or more) you'll need to configure each to use a separate port number.

Comment: i just want  to run 1 mosquitto file.how can it be done?and how to make sure that my port is not already in use?thanks in advance.

Comment: Mosquitto will run as a service on Windows, once started there is no need to start it again. If you want to stop it use the services tool to stop it. Or you've just left it running in a separate command window, in which case ctrl-c in that window will stop it

Comment: That worked and i m able to run mosquitto now!thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the **mosquitto.conf** in a bin folder in which you installed the mosquitto server.

Make sure all lines are commented with '#' especially the following line,
port 1883 or listener 1883.

then, find some available port or whether the port 1883 is used by using command like netstat.

In windows, you can use this,

netstat -an| findStr 1883

You have to change your default port on mosquitto when found any message from the prompt.

Append some specific number on the line below which is indicating the port whatever you prefer to.

```
listener XXX
protocol mqtt
```